# $.post() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, facebook-c#-sdk

I creating a fb app. I use FB.ui method apprequests to select friends to whom I send also want to post to wall. This looks like this.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
FB.init({
    appId: myappID,
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
    channelUrl  : 'http://localhost:3435/Content/channel.html'
});

function invite(){  
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.',
        data: 'tracking information for the user'
      },
function (response) {

      if (response && response.request_ids) {
          len = response.request_ids.length; //# of reqs
          var i = 0;

          for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            user_req_id = response.request_ids[i];
            FB.api('/me/apprequests/?request_ids=' + toString(user_req_id),
                   function (response) {
                     $.post("http://localhost:3435/Home/PostToWall", 
                            { request_ids: response['data'][0]['from']['id'] },
                            function (data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data); }
                           );
                    });
      }
    } else {
      //  alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  })
    };
</script>
```

As you can see I'm want to do a post request to a

```cs
[HttpPost, CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me,publish_stream,email")]
public ActionResult PostToWall(string request_ids)
{
   /* Post to Wall Logic */
   return View();   
}
```

This works fine with Chrome and Firefox, but in IE the Action isn't fired up.

I prepared a small sample javascript, which you can test. This is where the problem seems to be.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function CallPostToWall() {
    $.post("http://localhost:3435/Home/PostToWall", 
           { request_ids: 100001968250722 }, 
           function (data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data);}
          );
  };
</script>
<a href='#' onclick='CallPostToWall()'>Test Posting</a>
```

When this is tested in FF and Chrome, the alert return the actions expected html as if http://localhost:3435/Home/PostToWall?request_ids=100001968250722 was requested.

In IE on the other hand. I get somethin like:

```
<html><head><script type="text/javascript">
top.location = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=user_about_me,publish_stream,email&state=eyJyIjoiaHR0cDovL2FwcHMuZmFjZWJvb2suY29tL2NoaW5jenlrd3Nvc2llL0hvbWUvUG9zdFRvV2FsbCJ9&client_id=248066421875572&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3435/facebookredirect.axd";
</script></head><body></body></html>
```

I pretty lost with this.

Any thoughts?

Regards,
Simon

Comment: We can't test any of that cause it's on your own computer, we don't have access.

Comment: That's why I supplied the test code. You can just use it with any other sample Facebook-c#-SDK project

Comment: What are you expecting to see and what are you seeing?

Comment: Well I want the PostToWall action to be called. In Chrome and FF this does happen, but not in IE. In IE instead of a view returned by PostToWall, I get the last piece of code you see obove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is just a workaround. I've managed to get the $.post() running/returning the correct view by removing the CanvasAuthorize(...) attrinbute from the PostToWall definition

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostToWall(string request_ids)
{
   /* Post to Wall Logic */
   return View();   
}
```

As I understood, after reading a couple of posts on the web, this might be caused by IE preventing "cross-site-scripting"-like actions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!
I solved my problem which is because of  "same origin policy" and just raise in IE!:
I've just change the **URL** parameter from : **'http://mysite.com/api/'** to **'/api/'**
and it works!!!

hope it help some of you!